# How to pass data from client side to Server Side

Tags: c#, web-services, angular, post

I am trying to post  form data to service [My Post Response From Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fGY4.png)

It is hitting the method in service but problem lies in getting data.
CAn anyone suggest a method to retrive the data.

This is the class  at the client side

```
 - export class TravelRequestDetails
{
  public InitiatorName:string;
  public EmployeeName:string;
  public IntiatedDate:Date;
  public ProjectName:string;
  public PurposeOfTravel:string;
  public TravelFrom:string;
  public TravelTo:string;
  public StartDate:Date;
  public EndDate:Date;
}
```

This is my class at service side

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    public class TravelRequest
    {
        [JsonProperty("InitiatorName")]
        public string InitiatorName { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("EmployeeName")]
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("IntiatedDate")]
        public DateTime InitiatedDate { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("ProjectName")]
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("TravelFrom")]
        public string TravelFrom { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("TravelTo")]
        public string TravelTo { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("StartDate")]
        public Nullable<DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("EndDate")]
        public Nullable<DateTime> EndDate { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("PurposeOfTravel")]
        public string PurposeOfTravel { get; set; }


    }
```

and the method from service

```
 [Route("api/CreateRequest")]
        [HttpPost]
        public void CreateTravelRequest(TravelRequest travelDetail)
        {

            //travelDetail = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TravelRequest>(Convert.ToString(travelDetail));
            //// _travelRepository.CreateTravelRequest(travelDetail);
            //return Ok();
        }
```

i am confused what to put inside the method?any help

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [JsonResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult(v=vs.118).aspx) as your return type

```
         [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult CreateTravelRequest(TravelRequest travelDetail)
        {

          return Json(travelDetail, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```